# Trigger jstree event always

Tags: javascript, jquery, tree, jstree

I have a tree structure in which all the tree nodes are parent and sub folders. I want to display the files in the folders which the user tries to expand. So user user expand a node it shows the child nodes(sub folders) and files from the parent node in another div.

I am using "open_node.jstree" event to load some other scripts. But "open_node.jstree" is not firing if node has no children. I want to trigger an event if node is expanded irrespective of the node has children or not.

My code is follows

```
var dispJSTree = function () {
            $("#treedisp").jstree({
                'core': {
                    'data': {
                        "type": "POST",
                        "dataType": "json",
                        "contentType": "application/json;",
                        "url": "/xyz/example.asmx/GetJsFoldersTree",
                        "data": function (node) {
                            var nodeid = (node.id == "#") ? "" : node.id;
                            var originalSrc = node.original;
                            var moduleId = "";
                            if (typeof (originalSrc) === 'undefined' || originalSrc == null || originalSrc == "") {
                                nodeid = "";
                            }
                            else {
                                nodeid = (typeof (originalSrc.nodeid) === 'undefined' || originalSrc.nodeid == null || originalSrc.nodeid == "") ? "" : originalSrc.nodeid;
                                moduleId = (typeof (originalSrc.moduleId) === 'undefined' || originalSrc.moduleId == null || originalSrc.moduleId == "") ? "" : originalSrc.moduleId;
                            }

                            return JSON.stringify({ id: nodeid, moduleId: moduleId });
                        }
                    }
                },
                'plugins': ['contextmenu'],
                'contextmenu': {
                    'items': customMenu
                },                
            }).on('open_node.jstree', function (e, data) {
                var folderId = data.node.original.id;
                var moduleId = data.node.original.moduleId;
                getFiles(folderId, moduleId, filesDispDiv);
            });
        }
```

My only concern is "open_node.jstree" is triggered only the node has child nodes. Else it is not triggered. I wand to trigger an event if node is expanded.

Pl give a solution

Comment: How do you show that the node without children can be opened?

Comment: I don't need to show the node(empty node which contains no children), But I need to trigger a event that will trigger some other scripts to do other operations.

Comment: Can you use a `select_node` event?

Comment: I have a tree structure in which all the child nodes are parent and sub folders. I want to display the files in the folders which the user tries to expand. So user user expand a node it shows the child nodes(sub folders) and files from the parent node in another div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found a solution to this. The event "load_node.jstree" is always triggers irrespective of the contains the child nodes or not.

```
$("#treedisp").jstree().on('load_node.jstree', function (e, data) {
                    var folderId = data.node.id;
                    getFolderFiles(folderId, userOrOrgProfId, filesDispDiv);
                })
```

Answer (score 0):

for situation like this I'm handle on click event

```
 $("#mytree").on("click", ".jstree-anchor", function(e) {
             var obj = $("#mytreet").jstree(true).get_node($(this));           
    });
```

you cant use obj.id to access your clicked node id and ...